# Remove association model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, dry

Hi i would like to know if its possilbe to remove an association in rails.

Well, i have something similar to this:

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  include settings
end
```

On settings.rb i have something similar to this

```
module Settings
  attr_reader :person
  attr_reader :address

  def self.included(base)
      base.belongs_to :city
      base.belongs_to :entity
      [...]
  end

  [...]

end
```

On Home class the city model association on my particular case don't make sense. And i have to find a way to remove it to maintain my code DRY.

Thank you!

NOTE: Give me feedback before vote down please.

Comment: I can't remember any method like that in ActiveRecord, but I'd approach that problem from the opposite side anyway. I think it's much better not to add associations you don't need in the first place. One of the options is to move all `belongs_to` calls into a separate method that will accept list of required associations. In that case you'll have to call that method explicitly after including the module, but it still looks better than adding all and removing unnecessary associations.

Comment: If there is only one exception, put the different code into the Home class, for the other classes that reuse your module use the include. A lot of DRY is not convenient all times.

Comment: I think you're being a little pedantic about this... there's no reason to remove the methods other than just so the instance won't respond to them. And whatever the reason behind that is, well, it's just unclear. Clarify please why you want to do this at all.

Comment: It's not pedantic, it's a question of logic on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just don't want the methods then use `remove_method` to remove them.

Comment: i can do on my model class remove_method :city and it will work?